# Disable internal monitor

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm in a sticky siruation. I have notebook without its own monitor (the internal one) with external monitor connected. However, the laptop still recognizes the internal monitor as the main one, eventhough it IS NOT CONNECTED. My system is Fedora 30, I have made few pictures from lswh but cannot post them (it was possible to log in through switching to runmode 3 and startx). Can I somehow make the computer not recognize the port at all? Or what can I do?

Comment: 1. Try dragging the black bar at the top: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/how-to-change-the-primary-display-of-dual-screen-fedora-16  You might set the displays as mirrors (duplicates)... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/727165/is-there-any-way-to-mirror-displays-in-169

Comment: Look into `/var/log/Xorg.log` to see which driver you use (probably `intel`). Read the manpage (e.g. `man intel`) to see how a `xorg.conf` should look like to only use the output(s) you want. You can also login with `ssh` from a second computer while X is running, set `DISPLAY`, and experiment with `xrandr`. If you are unlucky, you may have to set all this on boot. In that case, read `dmesg` to see what's going on, and which fb driver you need to configure.